# Entity Framework with Stored Proc that optionally returns recordset

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a stored proc that returns a recordset normally, but in certain circumstances it doesn't return a recordset at all. This is causing EF some grief:

"The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'myDBContext.usp_MyProc_Result'. A member of the type, 'TheFirstColumn', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."

Is there a way I can tell it just return null or something like that if the proc doesnt return anything

Comment: why don't you fix your stored proc to return a empty set!

Comment: One because its not my proc, its the dba's. Two because it seems like a perfectly valid response. I have a hard enough time winning the ORM battle with the DBAs that I dont need to add fuel to their fire by forcing quirky changes

Comment: The quickest fix seems to be to use try + catch the specific exception. I assume that the sproc already has done its work when the exception is thrown.

Comment: I thought about that, the problem is that I am also using output parameters, and EF doesnt populate them when there is an exception

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever seen this issue with EF + MySQL when dealing with VERY highly concurrent stored-procedure calls that contain transactions, but once it happens the first time, it happens several thousand times more, very quickly.
Funnily enough, I've never had this error with EF + SQLServer and I use that a lot more frequently.

There are a few things I've done to rectify this issue:

### Database-level

Firstly you should update the stored procedure and implement some exception handling. 
*I know the OP said this wasn't possible for him, but it should be the first recourse anyway!* This example is in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `YourProcedureName` (IN YourParameter YourType)
BEGIN
    DECLARE STUFF;

    -- Thanks to tips from http://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/transaction-with-stored-procedure-in-mysql-server/
    -- and syntax from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SQLWARNING 
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK; 
        SELECT AnInstanceOfTheResultSet FROM YourTable WHERE 1 = 0; -- Force an empty result-set 
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
        -- Do your complex operations
    COMMIT;
END
```

### In-Code

Secondly, in code, wrap your EF call with the most specific Exception that is thrown, i.e.: EntityCommandExecutionException. 
Here's an example in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

```
YourType result = null;
try 
{ 
    result = yourContext.YourProcedureName(YourParameter).FirstOrDefault(); 
}
catch (EntityCommandExecutionException ecee) 
{ 
    // Log it? Handle it somehow... 
}
if (result == null)
{
    // Handle your error state
}

// Continue processing normally...
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As I know EF allow we create complex type based on the return value of stored.

You can follow this post

http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/03/01/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx

Comment: I already have a complex type to store the records in when I get them. The problem is that I don't always get records back. That is to say that NO recordset is returned, not a recordset with zero records, but no recordset at all